# RestHighLevelClient parameter [include_type_name] with Elastic 8.5.1

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

iam trying to run spring boot application with RestHighLevelClient **7.17.4** in compatibility mod with elastic **8.5.1** by fallowing [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/migrate-hlrc.html). When application try to call get, i've got the fallowing error:
`Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/*] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]]`

My configuration of RestHighLevelClient in compatibility mod:

```
@Value("${hs360.services.watchlist.mgmt.elasticsearch.host}")
private String elsHost;

@Value("${hs360.services.watchlist.mgmt.elasticsearch.port}")
private int elsRestPort;


@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public RestHighLevelClient sourceClient() {
    return new RestHighLevelClientBuilder(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elsHost, elsRestPort)).setRequestConfigCallback(r -> r.setConnectTimeout(60000).setSocketTimeout(90000)).build()
    ).setApiCompatibilityMode(true).build();
}
```

and snippet, when application try to call get:

```
GetIndexResponse indexResponse = restHighLevelClient.indices().get(new GetIndexRequest().indices("*"), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

From log of request i can obviously see, that request contains parameter **include_type_name**

```
org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [GET http://hs360-ss-s
ource-master:9200/*?master_timeout=30s&include_type_name=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&all
ow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=false] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-8.5.1-c1310c45fc534583afe2c1c
03046491efba2bba2 "[ignore_throttled] parameter is deprecated because frozen indices have been deprecated. Consi
der cold or frozen tiers in place of frozen indices."]
```

I know, that this parameter is deprecated, i though compatibility mod would handle this, but obviously, there is something else. I tried to search for solution, when i can remove parameter from request, but without success.

How could i remove that parameter from request or work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0 which supports ES 8.5 or downgrade Elastic to [whatever your Spring Boot version supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions)

Comment: thanks for the answer, we are not using Spring Data Elastic in any way. Configuration is completely different in doc you have posted. We used this [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/installation.html)

Comment: Then you need to use the version 8.5.1 of the RestHighLevelClient

Comment: Thats the problem, we have to use old api for now. In new version, there are some unsuported features which we need. Thats why we are using compatibility mod.